# Proper look of yaml file

Tags: java, yaml

I'm wondering whether my yaml file looks fine.

```
external:
  library:
    url:
      merlin:
        guides: https://merlin.pl/catalog/ksiazki-m10349074/poradniki-c468/
        romances: https://merlin.pl/catalog/ksiazki-m10349074/romanse-c1774/
        biographies: https://merlin.pl/catalog/ksiazki-m10349074/biografie-c100115/
        bestsellers: https://merlin.pl/bestseller/?option_80=10349074
        crime: https://merlin.pl/catalog/ksiazki-m10349074/kryminal-i-sensacja-c495/
        fantasy: https://merlin.pl/catalog/ksiazki-m10349074/fantastyka-c467/
        concrete:
          book: https://merlin.pl/%s/%s
        most:
          precise:
            book: https://merlin.pl/catalog/ksiazki-m10349074/?q=%s
      empik:
        guides: https://www.empik.com/ksiazki/poradniki
        romances: https://www.empik.com/ksiazki/romans
        biographies: https://www.empik.com/ksiazki/biografie-i-dokument
        bestSellers: https://www.empik.com/bestsellery/ksiazki
        crime: https://www.empik.com/ksiazki-sensacja-kryminal
        fantasy: https://www.empik.com/ksiazki/literatura-fantastyka
        concrete:
          book: https://www.empik.com/%s,%s,ksiazka-p
        most:
          precise:
            book: https://www.empik.com/ksiazki,31,s?sort=scoreDesc&q=%s
```

To be more concrete, I'm wondering if `concrete book` and `most precise book` should be done like I did or should looks like this:

```
concrete_book: https://merlin.pl/%s/%s
most_precise_book: https://merlin.pl/catalog/ksiazki-m10349074/?q=%s
```

If first option, then could you tell me how can I access this variables within class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties("external.library.url")`

the rest of yaml (categories). Im accessing via getters from class
e.g

```
package bookstore.scraper.urlproperties;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("external.library.url")
public class MerlinUrlProperties {

    private Merlin merlin = new Merlin();

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class Merlin {

        private String bestSellers;
        private String romances;
        private String biographies;
        private String crime;
        private String guides;
        private String fantasy;
    }
}
```

with e.g `className.getMerlin().getRomances();`

Comment: If you did `concrete_book`, then it would be a different property name, but if you did `concrete.book`, it's the same name, just written in shorthand in the file.

Comment: @Andreas I want to write in yaml convention. `concrete.book` would not be clear at all. That's why I use yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
concrete:
  book: https://merlin.pl/%s/%s
```

This means that `concrete` is a key in the `merlin` mapping, and its value is another mapping which contains the key `book` which maps to the scalar `https://merlin.pl/%s/%s`. That is most certainly not what you want to express.

That being said, [the docs suggest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) to use *Kebab Case*, i.e.

```
concrete-book: https://merlin.pl/%s/%s
```

This will bind to a class field named `concreteBook`. Underscores will be fine as well. There is absolutely no reason to do it with nested classes and I wonder how you came up with that.

Comment: Okay, so I will change concrete book and most precise book to concrete-book and most-precise-book so I will get access to it by `conreteBook` and `mostPreciseBook`.